# How to send 5 bytes with the same value from Android device via bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth, rfcomm

I have been using the Bluetooth chat example for transferring data over Bluetooth from my android device to another. I would like to know how to send 5 bytes with the value of: 0, 64, 0, 32, 152.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I have solved my problem with this, and it works! thanks guys.

```
public static byte[] reset(){
        byte[] values = new byte[]{0, 64, 0, 32, (byte) 152};


        return values;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

your code will be same as that and might roughly look like this.

```
get BluetoothAdapter
```

then

```
create Socket for specific device
```

you can then get

```
InputStream and OutputStream
```

from Socket use them to

```
read() and write()
```

there may be many examples available.